# Search string in all binary pesudo-code

Tags: ida, decompilation

How can I search pesudo code  string in all functions in binary with Ida??

Pesudo code I mean when press `F5` in Ida I can see psedo code of the binary (like in c)

I want to search for example where there is `while` string or `break` string in psudo code

Comment: please add some example of what do you mean

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik I edit my post with more details

Comment: But pseudo-code is only ever created on-demand, right? Really unclear what it is you want.

Answer (score 3):

In version 6.x of Ida (tweaks will likely need to be made for more recent versions), you would want walk each `Segment`, then you can enumerate each `Function`, and from there, run the hexrays decompiler.

This will enumerate all the functions, dump the pseudo code, and then search for the string 'foobar':

```
import sys, idc, idautils, idaapi

# Writes out the C function pseudo code, with the starting effective address
# returns: string
def DumpPseudoCode(ea):
    if not idaapi.init_hexrays_plugin():
        return ""

    f = idaapi.get_func(ea)
    if f is None:
        return ""

    try:
        cfunc = idaapi.decompile(f);
        if cfunc is None:
            # Failed to decompile
            return ""
    except:
        return ""

    lines = []
    sv = cfunc.get_pseudocode();
    for sline in sv:
        line = idaapi.tag_remove(sline.line);
        lines.append(line)
    return "\r\n".join(lines)

# enumerate all the functions and search for a string in the generated pseudo code
for segea in Segments():
    for funcea in Functions(segea, SegEnd(segea)):
        ccode = DumpPseudoCode(funcea)
        if ('foobar' in ccode)
            # do something
```